# My app won't open from the "open in..." menu

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uti

I am trying to design an app that will open a custom UTI.  I have changed the info.plist, and when I click on the file my app shows up in the "open in..." menu, but when I click on it nothing happens.  I have tried the same thing using a .pdf file ending and was successful, so why won't my custom UTI open?

Answer (score 0):

Because you got conflicts in your info.plist. You can try to roll back/jump to previous commit if you are using tower or github.Otherwise start with fresh copy of your initial project.
So that you can find that where you are getting conflicts.

Comment: I don't see any evidence in the question that the plist contains a merge conflict.